# Passing array from AuthController to login view in Laravel 5

Tags: authentication, laravel, controller

Am having a problem passing an array from Laravel's AuthController to auth.login view.  What am trying to do is retrieve data from News model and send it to the view.  I know how to use eloquent to retrieve data, passing from the controller to the view is my problem as I cannot see the how/where Laravel is rendering the view.

Comment: I've just come across this same problem. Did you ever find a way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Add an array as second parameter to the view method when returning it in the controller.

```
return view('greetings', ['name' => 'Victoria']); // in controller
```

Then in your view, you should be able to access the variable `$name` which should be equal to `Victoria`

```
var_dump($name); // in view
```

[More in the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#passing-data-to-views)

Comment: I tried this before.. AuthController doesn't seem to pass it to the register view. No idea if there is a bug or Auth/register.blade.php simply uses another Controller. But which one?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by passing the variable through the Controller on the redirect method.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what the objective is here, but you said:

> I cannot see the how/where Laravel is rendering the view.

So to answer that:

Laravel's AuthController pulls in a trait AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers which itself pulls in a few other traits, one being AuthenticatesUsers and another being RegistersUsers.

In AuthenticatesUsers you will find a method like so:

```
/**
 * Show the application login form.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function showLoginForm()
{
    $view = property_exists($this, 'loginView')
                ? $this->loginView : 'auth.authenticate';

    if (view()->exists($view)) {
        return view($view);
    }

    return view('auth.login');
}
```

There is likewise a similar method in the RegistersUsers trait.

This is where the AuthController returns its views.

If you need to tweak this behavior, or return the view with some data, you could override these methods in your controller, if this is really the best solution to your given situation.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found a better way to do that.

You can override the showRegistrationForm() method in AuthController.php and pass along the data you want to use in the view. Ex.:

```html
    public function showRegistrationForm()
    {
        $results = Model::all();
        return view('auth.register', ['results' => $results]);
    }
```